# C++ Dependencies directories between files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, directory, dependencies

My compiler has a problem to search files in the directories. I'm on windows 10.

First of all, my files are organized in this way:

- C:/mingw64/bin/g++ (my compiler is here)
- C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/main.cpp (my file)
- C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/SFML/include (my files.hpp)
- C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/SFML/lib (???)

I have 9 files .hpp which are:

- Audio.hpp
- Config.hpp
- GpuPreference.hpp
- Graphics.hpp
- Main.hpp
- Network.hpp
- OpenGL.hpp
- System.hpp
- Window.hpp

And I have my main.cpp which is an example to see if my SMFL works:

```
#include <Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is my compiler says: "**No such file or directory**" with **#include <SFML/Window.hpp>** in red.

I tried to find a solution through **VisualStudioCode** with the IncludePaths inside my **.json** on each file .hpp but it doesn't work.

I also tried on my terminal to put a command: **g++ -I/SFML/include main.cpp -o EX** but I have the error above.

Or: g++ -I/SFML/include/** main.cpp -o EX but this time it's **#include <SFML/System.hpp>** which is in red.

I don't understand why he put this error because I don't include it... It seems to not recognize my paths or to have a dependency between the .hpp. Maybe the solution is inside the directory "lib" but I don't know how to specify it or to manipulate it.

I'm blocked since yesterday and I hope you will help me.

Christophe.

Comment: your -I flag should point to a folder, like -I/SFML/include

You also probably want to include #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp> in your main.

Follow the official's SFML getting started to proper setup your project https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the tutorials concern Code::block or an old version of VisualStudio. I don't have their options. I'm trying to make a "Makefile" to link my libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i was you, i wouldn't bother making a makefile myself.

Instead i will use cmake to generate the makefile and let him compile both my code and SFML.

If you want to do it like that, you can just download cmake on their website.

- https://cmake.org/
  don't forget to add cmake into your path variable if you are on window

then in your project create a file named

- CMakeLists.txt
- A Lib folder where you have all your lib
- A Source folder where you have all your source file
- A Build folder where the compilation result will be

in your CMakeLists copy and paste that code for sfml with c++11

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(ProjectNAME)

# Source files
set(SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source")
set(LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")

#All the sources files listed
#List only the cpp file, header are automatically listed
set(SOURCES
        "${SRC_DIR}/main.cpp"
        )


# Executable definition and properties
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${SRC_DIR}")
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)

# SFML
set(SFML_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/SFML")

# this line is here to avoid having to move the dll into the build folder
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)


add_subdirectory("${SFML_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} sfml-graphics sfml-audio sfml-system sfml-window sfml-network)
```

Don't forget to put your main.cpp in the source folder and your SFML folder in the Lib Folder.
Pay attention to name correctly all the folder in the CMakeLists.txt

then if you are on linux with gcc or g++:

- open your terminal
- go into the Build folder
- execute the command "`cmake ..`"
- wait till it finish
- execute the command "`make`"
- wait till it finish
- launch your program with "`./ProjectNAME`"

if you are on window with mingw (don't forget to add mingw in your path):

- open your terminal
- go into the root folder
- execute the command "`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -B build/Debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`"
- wait till it finish
- go into the build folder
- execute the command "`mingw32-make -j`"
- wait till it finish
- launch your program with "`ProjectNAME.exe`"

And everything should work easily, without having to configure the make file yourself.
And if you want to learn more about cmake they have a great documentation

Now you just have to include <SFML/graphics.hpp>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I follow your instructions and I'm stuck at the path variable for the cmake. It didn't find. I downloaded on (C:\cmake) and I added to my path variable system but it doesn't recognize. I tried C:\make and C:\make\Source (because I think the cmake is here) but nothing. I search again.

Comment: Ok, I saw I didn't have the good file for my cmake. Now, it's fine. However, I have an error that I try to resolve and I think it will be good. It says my CMakeLists isn't here.

Comment: Ok, I put CMakeLists.txt when I named my file. It's a mistake. I just have to write CMakeLists. It compiles now but I have a last error: it stopped because there are not CMakeLists inside my lib/SFML folder and I don't understand why I have this error. Can you explain to me ? Thank you.

Comment: can you send a screenshot.

Comment: By the way, to ensure you have sfml in the lib folder, u should download it from github
https://github.com/SFML/SFML
and put it in the lib folder

Comment: I downloaded a bad version. Now, it works ! Thank you for your help !